# Windows Server 2012 - Find files related to a Role or Feature

Tags: powershell, windows

I have a strange requirement from a client. I need to be able to enumerate the list of files/folders that have been installed by a Role or Feature in Windows Server 2012 (R2 if the release# matters). I checked around TechNET, PowerShell and other documentation but could not find anything useful.

Let me know if this is possible (if yes, how?) at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about loading up a blank VM, start [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), and then installing the role or feature. Once the feature is installed you can review the process monitor log to see what changed.